# QR decomposition: Same results for Classical Gram-Schmidt and Modified Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, matrix-decomposition

I am implementing QR decomposition (in Fortran) for a complex-valued matrix, using Classical Gram-Schmidt and Modified Gram-Schmidt (and Householder). I was expecting that the Classical Gram-Schmidt would yield slightly different results than the Modified, due to its numerical instability (round-off errors). Instead, my obtained R matrices are the same for both occasions. Does anyone know why is this happening?

I'm using double precision.

Comment: PC processors have 80 bits floating-point registers. As long as values remain in these registers, higher than double precision accuracy can be preserved. This may "hide" the instability.

Comment: The error in the $R$ matrix will depend also on the condition number of the matrix. If you've generated the matrix randomly, then it's probably reasonably well-conditioned. To really stress test the algorithms, generate matrices with large condition numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference comes from your machine tolerance.  Your system will only allow for small numbers to some point.  If you use a number smaller than your limit, Gram Schmidt 'loses' it.

For example, suppose you have $\epsilon$ s.t. $\epsilon$ is your machines tolerance (it could be $2^{-64}$).  In other words, any smaller of a number and your system can't keep track.

Let's say you are using the number $\epsilon$, with Gram Schmidt it is entirely possible with the norm you could end up with a value such as $(1+ \epsilon ^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.  But $\epsilon ^2$ is much smaller than the limit of $\epsilon$ which results in $(1+ \epsilon ^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ being rounded to $1$.

Modified GS avoids this.  If your code is getting the same for both, then most likely it is because you are using numbers well within your machine's tolerance.  Try using a very small number and see what happens.